# Unsure on why .load() complete event isn't working

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm unsure on why this isn't working:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      setInterval(RefreshDiv, 2000);
    })

    function RefreshDiv(){
      $('#box').load('messages.php #box', function() {
        $('#box').on('load', function() {
          $('#box').scroll(0, 50);
        });
      });
    }
```

The tags are correct and the .load() part works every two seconds but I don't understand why my complete event to scroll down 50px isn't working?

I've also tried another method to scroll:

```
var log = document.querySelector('#box');
log.scrollTop = log.scrollHeight - log.clientHeight;
```

but this also doesn't execute on load

**Edit #1**

```
jQuery($ => {
      setInterval(RefreshDiv, 2000);
    })

    function RefreshDiv() {
      $('#box').load('messages.php #box', () => {
        $('#box').scrollTop(50);
      });
    }
```

Comment: There is no load event for a div. Just remove that and call `$('#box').scroll(0, 50);`

Answer (score 1):

The `load` event only fires on certain elements such as `img` and the `window` object. As such I presume `#box` is not one of them.

You don't actually need the load event handler anyway as the callback itself runs when the `load()` method completes its request. Try this:

```
jQuery($ => {
  setInterval(RefreshDiv, 2000);
})

function RefreshDiv() {
  $('#box').load('messages.php #box', () => {
    $('#box').scrollTop(5000);
  });
}
```

It's also worth noting that sending AJAX requests every 2 seconds is not ideal, as it will not scale as you have more concurrent visitors to your site, and can lead to server performance problems. There's likely to be a much better alternative, depending on what it is you're doing.

Comment: Hi, I did the same thing but I realised scrollTop() was the correct function, but it didn't seem to work either as I've written it similar to what you suggested in my Edit #1 but the load was still working and no errors appeared. I get that a 2 second reload isn't beneficial but right now it's just for testing and I don't plan on having a lot of users on my site anyway, but I'm trying to do something where a div refreshes and automatically scrolls to the bottom.

Comment: You're right it should be scrollTop - my bad. When you run your code, open the console and check for any errors